# C#: Bad design of class (first OOP)

Tags: c#, database, oop, console-application

This is homework!!! Please do not interpret this as me asking for someone to code for me.

My Program: http://pastebin.com/SZP2dS8D

This is my first OOP. The program works just fine without user input(UI), but the implementation of it renders my design partially ineffective. I am not using a List collection because of assignment restrictions. My main goal is to have everything running from the Transcript class. Here are some issues I am running into:

- Allowing the user to add new course without having to create a new instance of Transcript
  each time
- Associating the Courses added to a specific Quarter

Here is some pseudo code to show what I am trying to accomplish. I have been experimenting with it, but have yet to succeed.

```
Please enter the quarter: (user input)
Would you like to add a course? 

while (true)

Enter Course/Credits/Grade

//new Course information populated with user input 
transcript.AddCourse.to specific Quarter((Fall 2013) new Course("Math 238", 5, 3.9));
transcript.AddCourse.to specific Quarter((Fall 2013) new Course("Phys 223", 5, 3.8));
transcript.AddCourse.to specific Quarter((Fall 2013) new Course("Chem 162", 5, 3.8));
```

**MY QUESTION[S]:** Should I keep the Transcript class, or discard it? With the current functionality of creating a new course, is it possible to keep it this way while using UI, or do I need to head back to the chalk board and reconfigure?

Hopefully this is coherent and not too broad. If clarification is needed please ask and I will me more than happy to provide more details.

Comment: Is there a reason you have an array of `Student`s in your `Transcript` class?  I presumed with this design that a `Transcript` was per `Student`, so you would only need one.

Comment: On a side note, you're doing all your styling in Java style.  For example, you're naming a lot of properties `setXXX` or `getXXX`, when in C# it should just be `XXX`.  Also, in C#, function names first character is upper case.

Comment: @Gjeltema The design I had in mind was to use Transcript in place of a List. You are correct, the intention I have for Transcript is per student. I was attempting to create an empty list for students. I will try getting rid of the Student array, that makes complete sense.

Comment: @Gjeltema My first programming class (last quarter) was Java :). I appreciate the advice.

Comment: Alright - in that case, then I would endorse the design suggested by @TGH, with the only change being a reference to a single `Student` in the Transcript class, along with the collection of `Quarter` instances.  Also, I figured you had initially learned Java - that seems to be a standard these days in college.

Comment: Do you think it might benefit me to just get rid of the Student class all together and transfer the class info into the Transcript class?

Comment: There's a lot of ways of approaching this.  I think both of the answers shown so far are good approaches, and will work just fine.  In some ways knowing how the data will be retrieved when needed will help drive the design, but with homework it's usually not so easy to do.  I would probably keep the `Student` class around though - OOP is about small classes with single responsibility, short functions, and so on.  But if you brought its two fields into the Transcript class, it wouldn't be the end of the world (especially for homework).

Comment: I appreciate it. Once I complete my program, I will experiment more with my classes.

Comment: @Gjeltema I have been at it pretty much since I posted this. Here is my (quasi). Thanks again for the advice! [My AcademicTrascript Program](http://pastebin.com/NXrqnJY4)

Comment: Well, this is getting pretty lengthy and drawn out, but I'll throw a couple of comments.  First, it looks like you have a major flaw in your setup - Transcripts only holds 4 quarters.  What about your 2nd, 3rd and 4th years?  Nomenclature: don't add a type name to a type or variable name (don't call it QuarterEnum, call it Quarter; _quarterArray -> _quarters).  Also, Google "C# Autoproperty" - this will save you some typing and clean things up a bit.  This isn't everything, but it will get you a correct program, and clean it up a bit.

Comment: After you turn in your homework (when is it due?) come back and ping me via comment, and I'll help you go over this a bit more - I'll give you better style and flow suggestions.

Comment: @Gjeltema Thank you very much for the help and offered further support. I am always looking for ways to improve, especially with something as abstract as programming. I just turned in my assignment, and am preparing for two finals, but once complete I will clean things up from your advice and show you what I come up with.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would consider the following compositon

```
public class Transcript
{
  public Quarter[] Quarters{get;set;}
}

public class Quarter
{
  public Course[] Courses{get;set;}
}
```

You only need one instance of the transcript class. 
This will enable you to model n quarters (multiple years) with n courses per quarter.

In your input loop you can add new courses/quarters in response to user input

Comment: I appreciate it. I will implement this and let you know if I have any further questions. If not, I will select this question as answered!

Answer (score 3):

There are a lot of ways to model this problem and I think you're right to have a transcript class, but instead of thinking that a quarter has a set of courses I would suggest that which quarter a course is offered is a property of the course. For example:

```
public class Transcript
{
    private List<Course> courses_ = new List<Course>();

    public IEnumerable<Course> Courses {get { return courses_; }

    public IEnumerable<Course> GetCoursesFor(int year, int quarter)
    {
        return courses_.Where(course => course.Year == year && course.Quarter == quarter);
    }

    public void AddCourse(Course course)
    {
        courses_.Add(course);
    }
}


public class Course
{
    public int Year {get; private set;}
    public int Quarter {get; private set;}
    // ... other members
}
```

Comment: Lol, I never thought of it that way. Seems a lot easier associating the quarter to the course instead of the way I have it. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

you can try this

```
public enum Quarters
    {
        First,
        Second,
        Third,
        Fourth
    }
    class Courses
    {
        private Quarters ThisQuarter { get; private set; }
        private List<Tuple<Quarters, List<Courses>>> SchoolProgram = new List<Tuple<Quarters, List<Courses>>>();

        public int year { get; private set; }
        public string name { get; private set; }

        private Courses()
        {
            //load list from database or xml
            //each tuple has one quarters and a list
            // of associated courses
            //SchoolProgram.Add(new Tuple<Quarters, List<Courses>>(Quarters.First, new List<Courses>(){new Courses(2010,"Math",Quarters.First),
            //                                                                                       new Courses(2010,"English",Quarters.First),
            //                                                                                       new Courses(2010,"Physics",Quarters.First)}));
        }

        public Courses(int year,string name,Quarters q)
        {
            this.year = year;
            this.name = name;
            ThisQuarter = q;

        }

        public Courses GetCourse()
        {
            return SchoolProgram.Find(q => q.Item1 == ThisQuarter).Item2.Single(c => (c.year == this.year && c.name == this.name));
        }
    }

    public class Transcript
    {
        private List<Courses> SchoolProgram = new List<Courses>();

        public Transcript()
        {
            //maybe aditional logic here
        }

        public void AddCourse(int year,string name,Quarters q)
        {
            Courses c = new Courses(year, name, q);
            SchoolProgram.Add(c.GetCourse());
        }
    }
```

you can add additional logic about the grades and other stuff....best wishes

Comment: I originally was going to use enum for quarters. Also to help me calculate gpa & cumulative gpa, but scratched the idea. This give new perspective to it. Thanks